# Remove Function Javascript, knockout, c#, asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

Hi im trying to create something similar to planning poker. Currently I have it so you can create a game and I'm trying to make it so you can delete a game. Currently my delete deletes games but only temporarily if you hit refresh they are still there. I know what i have to do just not how to do it. I need the delete button to delete the game from the observable  array in my controller.

heres my code

Index( creates games)

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Planning Poker</title>
<style>
    .inlinetext {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#button').on('click', function (data) {
            $.post('data/games/create/?title=5', function (d) {  console.log(d) });
        })
    });
</script>
</head>



<body>
<h3 class='inlinetext'> Create Game: </h3>
    <input type="text" id="testtext" name="ime">
    <button id="button" >Create</button>


</body>

 </html>
```

Gamelist ( a page that lists the games , I want to be able to delete games from this list)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Game List</title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="Gamelist.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

            <h4>Games</h4>

            <ul data-bind="foreach: $data.games">
                <li>
                    Game <span data-bind="text: $index"> </span>:
                    <span data-bind="text: Title"> </span>
                    <a href="#" data-bind="click:  $parent.removeGames">Remove</a>
                </li>
            </ul>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Gamelist.js

```
function AppViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.games = ko.observableArray([]);

$.getJSON("/data/games", function (d) {
    self.games(d);
 });


 self.removeGames = function () {
    self.games.remove(this);
    }
}
$(function () {
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
});
```

Controller

```
using PlanningPoker.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace PlanningPoker.Controllers
{
public class GMController : ApiController
{
    private static List<Game> games = new List<Game>() {
            new Game() {
                ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Title = "D&D"
            }
        };

    [Route("data/games")]
    public IEnumerable<Game> GetAllGames() {
        return games;
    }

    [Route("data/games/create"), HttpPost]
    public Guid CreateGame(string title) {
        Game g = new Game() {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Title = title
        };

        games.Add(g);

        return g.ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at your `self.removeGames` function: What is the scope of `this`? I'd recommend to use the actual item that is passed by knockout itself. `self.removeGames = function(item) {self.games.remove(item);}`

Comment: You also need to perform an ajax request to remove the item from the server from the removeGames function

Answer (score 0):

Step 4 of the Knockout tutorial [Working with Lists and Collections](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections) demonstrates exactly what you are trying to achieve.

```
self.removeGames = function(game) { self.games.remove(game) }
```